# Running yii2 script using Windows Task Scheduler results in 0xFF

Tags: php, yii2, windows-task-scheduler

I want to run my action method in yii2 advanced automatically. I put the code on the console/controllers. This is the code:

MailController.php

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
use Swift_TransportException;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSend()
    {
        $mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom('if414024@students.del.ac.id')
            ->setTo('if414024@students.del.ac.id')
            ->setSubject('Testing');
        try
        {
            $mail->send();
        }
        catch (Swift_TransportException $ste)
        {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Then I make this configuration from actions menu in task scheduler:

Program/script: `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

Add arguments (optional): `-f C:\xampp\htdocs\Baru\advanced\console\controllers\MailController.php`

I want to run send action. But the result in task scheduler is 0xFF and I don't get the email. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the controller action this way:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe c:\path\to\your\application\yii mail/send
```

or

```
c:\path\to\your\application\yii.bat mail/send
```

You are calling yii, and not the controller script directly. The controller and action (the route) is just a parameter.

See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2/) or the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html) for more information.

Comment: Please guide where to put this command in task scheduler. I am not trying to send mail instead I need to insert a row in a table. When I run controller/action in console I am able to insert a record. But when running through task scheduler the record is not getting saved in the database. There are two fields in task scheduler. Program and arguments. Where to put your answer. I am not facing any kind of errors in the scheduler. Task completed successfully is displayed.